# Xcode cordova project - pods

Tags: xcode, cordova, cocoapods, publishing

I have built and published a cordova app with android on my windows PC.
I have copied entire cordova project to a usb drive and transferred the project to a Mac to publish the iOS version.

I can navigate to the platforms/ios directory and open the xcode workspace file. When I try to build the project for the emulator I get the message:

pods-debug.xcconfig:2:could not find included file 'Pods/Target Support Files/' then the reference is to my windows files: C:\path\platforms\ios...

I have tried to deintegrate and reinstall pods through the terminal, and I can remove them and but i get a message saying that 'the workspace referencing the Pods project still remain'
and the problem with building persists.

I suspect that I need to try and rebuild the pods in Xcode but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I had to reinstall cordova. using the command line I changed all permissions to allow me to update the $PATH so that cordova commands on the mac could be used.

Then I had to remove platform iOS and re-add it

The I had to go into into platform/ios and run these commands:

pod deintegrate
pod install

After that I could enter xcode by clicking on the workspace and I could perform a test build